# If element hasClass, check the checkbox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a class that adds a fake checkbox and using jQuery, once the user clicks it, add the checked state class to the fake checkbox.

**CSS**

```
.fake-checkbox {  /* ... */  }
.fake-checkbox.checked-state {  /* ... */  }
```

**HTML**

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="fake-checkbox"></div>
</label>
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {
  $('.fake-checkbox').click(function() {
    // Check if fake-checkbox has class checked-state, then remove the class checked-state and vice versa.
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked-state')) {
      $(this).removeClass('checked-state');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('checked-state');
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Now, I also want to make the input checkbox in its checked state at the same time when the class is added and in its unchecked state when the class is removed.

I know this can be done with `element.checked = true` but not in jQuery.

How can I achive this?

**EDIT**

This is surely different and not a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery) cause we're in a different case, although there's a similarity about 'ticking a checkbox using jQuery' but still not a possible duplicate.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting "checked" for a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/setting-checked-for-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: I would urge you to look at another one of your answers: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39703074/2117156

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the `checkbox` is immediate preceding  sibling, you can use [`.prev()`](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) then set the property using [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method

```
(function($) {
  $('.fake-checkbox').click(function() {
    // Check if fake-checkbox has class checked-state, then remove the class checked-state and vice versa.  
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked-state')) {
        $(this).removeClass('checked-state');      
        $(this).prev(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('checked-state');
        $(this).prev(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Above code can be simplified as

```
(function($) {
  $('.fake-checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked-state');
    $(this).prev(':checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('checked-state'));
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: This could be simplified as `$(this).hasClass('checked-state')` is a `Boolean` value, `toggleClass` could be used...I was suggesting `.toggleClass( className, state )` approach...

Comment: I'll try this one. Will be back soon :)

Comment: Thanks for this :)

Comment: @Satpal Also, there's a conflict for `:checkbox` that already has the `checked` attribute. On first click, the class is removed but `:checkbox` is still checked, then on another clicks it became opposite (when the class is added, `:checkbox` is not checked` and vice versa). How can I fix this?

Comment: @Satpal It was working on a `:checkbox` which is not contained in a `<label>`. I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgec5xmw/) using Bootstrap 3 framework. Please see it and tell me what's wrong with it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the jQuery answers, i would like to suggest (*for this specific case*) a CSS only solution, since the checkbox and the `.fake-checkbox` are siblings.

**CSS**

```
.fake-checkbox {  /* ... */  }
:checked + .fake-checkbox{  /* ... */  }
```

**HTML**

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="fake-checkbox"></div>
</label>
```

**Demo**

```css
.fake-checkbox {  color:#ccc;  }
:checked + .fake-checkbox{  color:green;  }
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="fake-checkbox">fake</div>
</label>
```

---

As for a jQuery answer i would suggest you monitor the state of the actual checkbox instead of manually testing the states.

```
$('label :checkbox').on('change', function(){
  $(this)
    .siblings('.fake-checkbox')
    .toggleClass('checked-state', this.checked);
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$('label :checkbox').on('change', function(){
  $(this)
    .siblings('.fake-checkbox')
    .toggleClass('checked-state', this.checked);
})
```

```css
.fake-checkbox {  color:#ccc;  }
.fake-checkbox.checked-state {  color:green;  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <div class="fake-checkbox">fake</div>
</label>
```

Comment: I'm guessing that in practice, the _actual_ checkbox is hidden.

Comment: @JamieBarker it doesn't matter, since they are contained in a label. Wherever you click in the label it will toggle the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks but on one of your codes, there are times that the elements are not contained in a label so I use the .click() event not .change(). +1

Comment: @ChainTrap that is cool. I was going with the original html in your question. Whatever works better :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#yourCheckboxSelector').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check a checkbox using JQuery. 
Using the prop method. 
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-check-uncheck-a-checkbox-input-or-radio-button/

Use this

**HTML**

```
<label>
  <input id="real-checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <div class="fake-checkbox"></div>
</label>
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {
  $('.fake-checkbox').click(function() {
    // Check if fake-checkbox has class checked-state, then remove the class checked-state and vice versa.  
    if ($(this).hasClass('checked-state')) {
        $(this).removeClass('checked-state');      
        $( "#real-checkbox" ).prop( "checked", false );
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('checked-state');
        $( "#real-checkbox" ).prop( "checked", true );
    }
  });
}(jQuery));
```